# API to get all users with specific text in profile

Tags: 2013, user-profile, api

How can I use an api to get all users with a specific text (hashtag) in their user profile field "about me"?

Is this the correct way?

```
https://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext=%27aboutme:%22*myhashtag*%22%27&sourceid=%27B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31%27
```

How can I search for #myhashtag instead of myhashtag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `%23` in place of the hashtag. That is the ASCII representation, the same way `%22` replaces the quotes in your example...

Updated query:

```
https://mysite/_api/search/query?querytext=%27aboutme:%22%23myhashtag*%22%27&sourceid=%27B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31%27
```